# Move a draggable to a dragtarget automatically for the user in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

Here is my use case, I'm using draggable containers and a dragtarget (container with the question mark) for this little game (see linked image).

I've built that logic so far, so if the user drags the "i" in the image linked below, it will be accepted and go to the next word.

My question is: is there a way in flutter to allow the user to just **tap** on the draggable containers and make them move automatically to the dragtarget (using the logic already defined in the onAccept property of the dragtarget widget) ?

[Refered screen image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5cmt.png)

Comment: is this issue solved ?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. As the name says `Draggables` meaning it has to be dragged. Look what the official documentation says about `Draggables and DragTarget`

Draggable

> A widget that can be dragged from to a DragTarget.

DragTarget

> A widget that receives data when a Draggable widget is dropped.

I hope this helps.